# Estimation of a positive Integral

Tags: integration

$\int ^{T}_{t} f(x)dx\leq C+\int ^{T/2}_{t} f(x)dx$ for $t\in \left [ 0, T\right ]  \Rightarrow 
\int ^{T}_{T/2} f(x)dx\leq C$ ,$f$ is a positive function and $C$ is apositive constant.
Is this implication correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use that
$$\int_a^b f =\int_a^c f + \int_c^b f $$
and that
$$\int_a^b f = -\int_b^a f . $$

**Answer:** $$\int_t^T f \leq C +\int_t^{T/2} f \Rightarrow \int_t^T f - \int_t^{T/2} f \leq C$$
But $$\int_t^T f - \int_t^{T/2} f = \int_t^T f + \int_{T/2}^t f = \int_{T/2}^T f$$
and therefore
$$\int_{T/2}^T f \leq C .$$
So yes, this implication is correct.

Comment: I have 
$\int ^{T}_{t} f(x)dx\leq C$  for $t\in \left [ 0, T\right ]$.....(1)
If the implication is correct , then (1) $\Rightarrow  \int ^{T}_{T/2} f(x)dx\leq C$ .

Comment: I thought you have trying to prove it. I edited my answer, please take a look at this now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I think there is a problem , the function  F(t) =$∫_{t}^{T/2}f(s)ds$   has not a cnstant sign  ,for  $T/2\leq t $ it is negative.

Comment: I think it is not a problem.

Comment: Can me deduce direct that $∫_{t}^{T }f(s)ds$$\leq$ C then $∫_{T/2}^{T}f(s)ds$$\leq$ C?

Comment: Of course, intuitively yes! But the formal proof is in this way that I wrote.

Comment: Yes  this is true the problem is when C depends of t, like C=g(t).